# Saving `Graphics` is just transparent

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap

Here is some pseudocode of what I am doing. Everything worked fine but then I tried to save my results. The saving also works but the image turns out to be transparent. Any idea what could cause this odd behavior?

```
static Graphics G = Panel.CreateGraphics();

//some painting -> shows up correctly on the panel

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(500, 500, G);//bitmap is transparent!
bitmap.Save("path/test1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: When you use CreateGraphics() you are just splattering pixels directly to the screen.  They don't end up in the bitmap.  Don't use CreateGraphics, implement the panel's Paint event.  Now you can use its DrawToBitmap() method to generate the bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the `Bitmap` constructor you are using says:

> Initializes a new instance of the Bitmap class with the specified size and with the resolution of the specified Graphics object.

Which means it just gets the resolution from the `Bitmap`. It does not paint anything to the bitmap. Either use `Graphics.FromImage` or, as Hans Passant mentions, the `Control.DrawToBitmap` method.

My personal preference, have I a need to paint to both the screen and a bitmap, would be to create a method that does the painting (taking a `Graphics` object as an argument). I can then call this either in a `Paint` event handler, or from other code to generate a bitmap.

Also, in general, never use `Control.CreateGraphics`. The proper way of drawing is in the `Paint` event of a control.

Answer (score 0):

This will draw the Bitmap but wont show up in the panel. If showing is mandatory, then you have to implement it on the **Paint** event.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Panel.Width, Panel.Height);

Panel.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, Panel.Width, Panel.Height));

Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

Pen selPen = new Pen(Color.Blue);
grp.DrawRectangle(selPen, 10, 10, 50, 50);
bmp.Save("d:\\check3.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```